# mod_expires sending Cache-Control headers for 3## status codes

Tags: apache, redirect, cache-control, browser-cache, mod-expires

Apache is sending Cache-Control headers for 3## status codes, like 302 redirects. This is causing Firefox (possibly starting with Firefox 5) to cache the 302 redirects--which results in an infinite redirect loop for some of my pages.

Here are the settings that I am using in my `httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A600
</IfModule>
```

If I remove the ExpiresDefault setting, the problem goes away, so I am confident that this is the exact setting that is causing the problem. If I change `ExpiresDefault A600` to `ExpiresByType text/html A600` the problem is still there.

I'd like to have browsers cache my content by default, but this is a deal-breaker.

**Are there any settings I can use to tell Apache to send a different Cache-Control header for 3## status codes?**

Answer (score 0):

If you add the Cache-Control headers in your application, which builds the redirect, apache will not overwrite it.

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Sat, 04 Feb 2012 07:02:38 GMT
```

if you use apaches mod_rewrite to do the redirect you could add the headers with the 
[mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html#header) module.